# Windows Task Scheduler job created with octopus stops after some time

Tags: .net, windows, scheduled-tasks, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I have application as a set of asp.net micro services. 
Each service is presented by simple console application that use self hosted Web Api. 
I am using Octopus Deploy to deploy these services to the server.
Octopus create Windows scheduler task for each service and set

```
$ExecutionTimeout = New-TimeSpan -Days 9999
```

I can find the same value in Windows task scheduler UI of created task.

[image: Schedule Settings]

**My problem is:** after some time of working (about 2 weeks) all my services are going down. There are no exceptions or so in my services, and they are going down all at the same time.

I cant find out why? I set execution time out for more then 20 years!!!!
This issue is reproducing on different Windows Server versions.

I can also found this event into my task history log:

```
Task Scheduler terminated "{CF7BA44C-CB14-4737-89B2-C7261CFC997E}"  instance of the "\XXXX\XXX_SERVICE_NAME"  task due to exceeding the time allocated for execution, as configured in the task definition. User Action: Increase the configured task timeout or investigate external reasons for the delay.
```

Here is PowerShell code of task creation that is executing by Octopus:

```
    New-Item $InstallFolder -type directory

    $FilePath = $InstallFolder + '\' + $ExecutableNameParam
    $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $FilePath -WorkingDirectory $InstallFolder

    $Trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
    $RestartInterval = New-TimeSpan -minute 1
    $ExecutionTimeout = New-TimeSpan -Days 9999
    $Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -DontStopOnIdleEnd -RestartCount 10 -RestartInterval $RestartInterval -WakeToRun -StartWhenAvailable -ExecutionTimeLimit $ExecutionTimeout
    $Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "LOCALSERVICE" -LogonType ServiceAccount

    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -TaskName $TaskName -Settings $Settings -Principal $Principal
```

*Please let me know in comments if you think I should add some additional information about my environments into this question.*

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**
I had also expire disabled into my trigger settings:

[image: Trigger Settings]

If I understand correctly it's mean that there is no expiration at all for this trigger.

Comment: Perhaps this has some information: https://serverfault.com/questions/604083/task-scheduler-2-0-difference-between-stop-task-if ?

Comment: I beleive i have both options configured properly (as I can see) I will recheck second one tomorrow morning

Comment: I have utc+3 time  now, to understend when the morning are. I am new in stackoverflow does its provide users time zones? I cant find

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't provide time zones but it does provide rough locations. I'm in UTC-0500.

Comment: I have check expiration into my trigger settings and it seems to be correct. I've updated question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Difficult one!

But I think you'll find most of what you need here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315549(v=ws.10).aspx

Particularly this section:

> The task was stopped due to a configured setting. Possible causes include:
>
> - The task ran for longer than the maximum configured run time.
> - The task was configured to stop when the computer switched to battery power.
> - The task was configured to stop when the computer is no longer idle.
> - The task was configured to stop when a new instance of the task is triggered.

Basically the error message is broader than just that one setting for expiration!

Comment: I think no one of this are applicable to this case: all configuration looks valid, no new instances are triggered(it should be Ok if new one is replace old), no battery on my server, except I don't really understand "The task was configured to stop when the computer is no longer idle."

Comment: If a new one *replaces* the existing one then that, presumably, would trigger a new instance of the task!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

For some reason

`$ExecutionTimeout = New-TimeSpan -Days 9999`

does not work as expected. Omitting this setting fixed my problem.